# Sum of Two Triangular Numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

What numbers can be written as the sum of two triangular numbers? i.e.,

$$\frac{x(x+1)}{2}+\frac{y(y+1)}{2}=z $$

$4z+1$ is either the sum of two squares or itself a square. Why?

Comment: Your pattern does not hold.  Try $x=5$ and $y=3$ giving $z=21$ and $4z+1 = 85$.

Comment: Didn't even notice that and now I feel dumb. Thanks.